# How to connect Shopify'API to Shippingbo?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, wms, oms

We would like to connect SHOPIFY and SHIPPING BO together rather than do it manually every day when we have a product update.
We have this documentary (https://developer.shippingbo.com/ + https://developer.shippingbo.com/docs/external-wms/f3hn9cxx2c4np-product-management) but it seems "too easy"

This is the script we tried to use:

```bash
curl --request GET \
  --url https://app.shippingbo.com/products \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'X-API-TOKEN: ' \
  --header 'X-API-USER: ' \
  --header 'X-API-USER-ID: ' \
  --header 'X-API-VERSION: '
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You don't read the right documentation, please use this one: https://developer.shippingbo.com/docs/api/wmyaww0hkv422-connect-an-order-source

But it's gonna be easy too